# jQuery Replacing, Using arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, replace

```
var searchp   = $('body'),
    searchval = searchp.html(),
    name      = ['Abraham Lincoln', 'George Washington'];
    cname     = name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, ''),
    restr     = searchval.split(name).join('<a href="#" data-name="'+cname+'">'+name+'</a>');

searchp.html( replacestr );
```

I need some help with a litte replace function. It works fine if I use name= 'string name', but I can't get it to work with arrays.
Hopefully you can help me.

Comment: The split/join technique to replace all occurences only works for a string. If you want to use an array, you'll have to loop.

Comment: FYI, you have a `;` after the Array which makes `cname` and `restr` global variables. I prefer to use leading commas on each line (below the `var`) instead of trailing commas to make it very clear that all the commas are present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to call `toLowerCase()` on an Array which provides no `toLowerCase()` method. Instead you should specify an item in that array like:

```
cname     = name[0].toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, ''),
```

This is easy to spot of you open the console of your browser as running it in Chrome gave me this message:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object Abraham Lincoln,George Washington has no
>   method 'toLowerCase'

As comments on your questions indicate you probably don't want to hard code the index of the element but instead use a loop. I tried to fiddle around with your code but it seems some input from `#body` is missing to get some semantic in your lines so all I can provide is one suggestion how to loop over an array of srings:

```
var name = ['Abraham Lincoln', 'George Washington'];
$(name).each(function(key, value){
    console.log(value.toLowerCase());
});

​
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
I got it working, but I placed the replacestr variable inside the each function, so it get overwritten, by the second array item.
Other than that it works.
Also I changed this:
var replacestr = searchval.replace(regexname, '<a href="#" data-name="'+cname+'" class="vcard-call">'+name+'</a>');